# Blender can't add armature anymore

Tags: mesh, modifiers, rigging, armature, parent

So I recently encountered an error where I cannot add an armature to my mesh, so I reinstalled Blender and the issue still persists, I've tried looking up other answers, there's no vertex weight groups, I've tried to add/remove armature modifier but nothing seems to work.

Anytime I try to parent an armature to a mesh it's met with 'Clear parent'. I've tried clicking clear parent which does nothing, and now when I open other blender files the same thing happens.

[image]

I'm out of ideas on what to do, please does anyone know what's happening?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right shortcut (Ctrl+P) ? Did you try using the menu (Object/Parent) ?

Comment: Yes, Ctrl + P brings up that menu. Parenting in the object tab also does nothing. I even tried naming conventions I.e calling the root bone root, and changing armature name. The shortcut was working not even 3 hours ago which is why I'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help troubleshooting, select the mesh and check what's on its parent field.

Then, as thibsert suggested, try to use the menu instead of the shortcut, it looks like you're telling the computer "Alt P" and not "Ctrl P". Did you switch phisically the two buttons on your keyboard? Or wrongly mapped them in your OS?

If the problem persist, try uploading your file.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. Bringing up the menu works.. I don't know why, but Blender did not have the key bindings mapped correctly. Restoring that fixed the issue, thanks!

Comment: Perfect, please mark the answer as "accepted".